# How can I addNodes to Server from Client side by milo?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have tried to addNode to Server from Client side like this:

```
        AddNodesItem newItem = new AddNodesItem(
                new NodeId(2,"Vehicles").expanded(),
                Identifiers.Organizes,
                new NodeId(2,"Vehicles/vehicle2").expanded(),
                new QualifiedName(2,"Vehicles/vehicle2"),
                NodeClass.Object,
                null,
                new NodeId(2,"Object/Types/Vehicle").expanded());

        List<AddNodesItem> items = new ArrayList<AddNodesItem>();
        items.add(newItem);

        client.addNodes(items).get();
        future.complete(client);
```

but I only got the error:

```
[main] ERROR Client1.Client - Error running client example: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_ServiceUnsupported, message=The server does not support the requested service.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_ServiceUnsupported, message=The server does not support the requested service.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at Client1.AddNode.run(AddNode.java:37)
    at Client1.Client.run(Client.java:103)
    at Client1.AddNode.main(AddNode.java:18)
```

I searched, that maybe I should do the server conf firstly, but how?
Any guide or answer will be helpful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your client code looks okay, but this will only work against a server that has implemented and supports the Node Management services.

The Milo example server does not implement these services, so you’ll have to find a different server to test against.